# Watch File Contents at Runtime In Netbeans

Tags: c, file, debugging, netbeans

In My program i open a file and certain changes are being written to the file , so when i debug the program in netbeans (7.1) i want to see the contents at each stage , as i go through the break points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to see the real time changes to the contents of a file as you step through your program in a debugger.  In general the debugger is not great at displaying the contents of a file.  The debugger is designed to display the state of the running program and not the state of external items such as the file system.

However you can easily watch the contents of the file through an external editor such as gVim or likely the actual IDE you're using.  Most editors will detect the contents of the file changing on disk and prompt you to reload when it changes.

Comment: The problem is several thousands of files are being changed and also the rate of modification is very high , such that before i could click reload the value might have been rewritten !